# About -lsqlite3.0 SQL library

Tags: ios, sdk

Hi I am integrating the FB SDK 3.0 Beta with IOS 6. I am wondering for what purpose I need to add -lsqlite3.0 in "other linker flags"?

Answer (score 3):

From the `ld` [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> -lx
>   This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or libx.a in the library search path. If string x is of the form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places, but without prepending `lib' or appending`.a' or `.dylib' to the filename.

So, `-lsqlite3.0` tells the linker to use a library called `libsqlite3.0.a` when linking your app. In Xcode, I believe this is equivalent to adding the libsqlite3.0 library in the `Build Phases`->`Link binary with libraries` panel.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's probably right. Forgot that Apple allow /themselves/ dynamic libraries...